# ASP.NET Core Web API swagger page not working when deployed to Azure Appservice

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0

I just created basic Web API using Visual Studio 2022 > create new project > selected the C# ASP.NET Core Web API template. And it created the weatherforecast Web API and everything worked fine on my local system.

[image]

But when I deploy this to Azure Appservice, I get a 500 error. Any idea what's going on?

[image]

Comment: How are you deploying it to Azure? I think some files or dependencies may be missing. Do you have any logging in place? if no, you could enable the stdout logs to see more information about the server error. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/troubleshoot-azure-iis?view=aspnetcore-6.0#aspnet-core-module-stdout-log-azure-app-service

Comment: By default, the swagger stuff is in an if statement: if environment is development. Check your startup file.

Comment: This issue was related to 500 error. So a7mdo's answer is wrong.

Comment: Please open your azure portal, and find application insight in left pannel and enable it. Then find the Failures in application insight, and check the details.

Comment: If it not useful, you also can find the application event log in Diagnose and solve the problem.  You can update the question later, if you find any details. I believe your application has some wrong setting and cause the crash issue.

Comment: And if we can't find any issue or all steps not work, we should create a new app service, then test again.

Comment: @JasonPan Yes, I deleted the appservice and recreated the app once again and this time it worked.

Comment: @roney Allow me to summarize the comments into an answer. This may help community members experiencing similar issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, when we use Swagger, we will encounter a 404 error when publishing to Azure App Service. This is because swagger is used by default in development. But we have this problem and encountered a 500 error.

**For 500 errors, we first look at the code and environment configuration issues at the project level.**

1. It works well locally, there is a problem after publishing, there may be a problem with the parameters of some configuration files.
2. Once we have determined that there are no problems with the project files, we can only view the problem with the help of application insight and Diagnose and solve the problem.
3. Finally, you can only delete the current app service resource and recreate an app service with the same name for retesting.

---

I had a similar issue before, and we solved it by recreating the app service. Later, I also tried searching, and *some people said that when creating an app service, you may encounter instances in some areas that are being maintained or updated, resulting in the created app service being in a bad state [The odds are very small].*

I think this claim is credible because I once tried opening two Azure portal pages, one of which commits the operation to create the service and the other refreshes the page. In case of not creating successfully, we will see that another page can already see that the service created by the commit is in the resource group.

#### In short, trying to delete and recreate Azure App Service with confidence that there are no issues with our code is an effective means.